# Is parentsUntil() the best function to use? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the html:

```
     <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
           <div class="c">
             <div class="d">
             </div>
           </div>
          <div class="d">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Im interested in the selecting the parent element with class `a` applied to it when any element with the class 'd' is clicked.

I have the following javascript / jQuery, but it seems very messy. Is there a neater way?

```
<script>
   $('.d').click(function(){
      var elementA =  $(this).parentsUntil('.a').last().parent();    
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You [want](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `$(this).closest('.a')`.

Answer (score 5):

you can also do:

```
$(".d").click(function() {
    // parents() will walk up through parent nodes. If you
    // pass a selector, the set will be filtered. If not,
    // you get the full list of parent elements.
    var elementA = $(this).parents(".a");
});
```

docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

hope that helps! cheers.